# Array expressions in Java

Tags: java

Consider the following expressions in Java.

```
int[] x={1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] y={5, 6, 7, 0};

x=y;
System.out.println(x[0]);
```

Would display `5` on the console because `x` is made to point to `y` through the expression `x=y` and `x[0]` would obviously be evaluated to `5` which is actually the value of `y[0]`.

When I replace the above two statements with the following statement combining both of them into a single statement,

```
System.out.println(x[(x=y)[3]]);
```

it displays `1` which is the value of `x[0]` even though it seems to be equivalent to those above two statements. How?

Comment: You should never use such expressions. They're just confusing, error-prone and hard to debug.

Comment: They still exist and we must know everything associated with such stuff in Java or in any language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the third index in the array y points to is 0, so 1 is the correct output.

So you have

`x[(x=y)[3]]`

which is `x[y[3]]`, but `y[3]` is 0, because arrays are 0-indexed, and `x[0]` is 1.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `x = y` produces the new x inside the index. So now `x[3] = y[3] = 0` and `x[0] = 1`, because it still uses the old `x` array on the outside.

Answer (score 1):

The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.

```
...println(x[y[3]]); // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x[(x=y)[3]]
```

breaks down to

```
int[] z = y; // new "temp" array (x=y) in your expression above
int i = z[3]; // index 3 in y is 0
System.out.println(x[i]); // prints x[0] based on the value of i...which is 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the precedence here

lets take a look at this

we have following expression

> x= 2 + 5 *10

so on running the about expression it first multiply 5 * 10 then add it with 2 and assign it to the x because the precedence of "=" is least

> x[(x=y)[3]]
>   in this case what confuses the most is that (x = y ) term, and most of programmers think that it assigns the reference of y to x first then proceed with the remaining part but
>   here assignment operator is resolved least

that's why when you try to print the x[0] after the above expression is run, then i will give value of 5 because the zeroth index of y contains 5